# Setting CustomComponent(TEDIT) MaxLength Property not working

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have created a new component which is derived from TEdit. In the below code, I am setting MaxLength Property to 10 after setting **AllowValues to true**.

I set the component on form and set the **AllowValues to true** and run the application and edit box is allowing more than 10 characters. whats wrong with my code?

```
unit DummyEdit;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Controls, StdCtrls,Dialogs,Windows,Messages;

type
  TDUMMYEdit = class(TEdit)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FAllowValues : Boolean;
    FMaxLength: Integer;
    Procedure SetAllowValues(Value : Boolean);
    procedure SetMaxLength(Value: Integer);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  published
    { Published declarations }
    Property AllowValues : Boolean read FAllowValues write SetAllowValues;
    property MaxLength: Integer read FMaxLength write SetMaxLength default 0;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('DUMMY', [TDUMMYEdit]);
end;

{ TDUMMYEdit }


procedure TDUMMYEdit.SetAllowValues(Value: Boolean);
begin
  if FAllowValues <> value then
    FAllowValues := Value;
  if FAllowValues then
    MaxLength := 10
  else
    MaxLength := 0;    
end;

procedure TDUMMYEdit.SetMaxLength(Value: Integer);
begin
  if FMaxLength <> Value then
  begin
    FMaxLength := Value;
    if HandleAllocated then SendMessage(Handle, EM_LIMITTEXT, Value, 0);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working on an answer I realized that you *re-invented* the `MaxLength` property for your custom edit. Was that your intention? Unless I'm mistaken all that currently differs is that you accidentally introduced the bug that is topic of this question. Your code should work if you hadn't introduced that property.

So one way to solve your issue is to remove the `MaxLength` property from `TDUMMYEdit`, instead rely on the one `TCustomEdit` implements.

Your issue is that when your code takes effect during component streaming from DFM, no `Handle` is allocated, `HandleAllocated` returns `False` and your `EM_LIMITTEXT` message will not be sent. Setting the `AllowValues` property later on, e.g. in an event handler of your form, would work as you'd expect, as at that time, a handle is allocated.

A way to fix this can be found looking at`TCustomEdit` in `Vcl.StdCtrls` - code you might have taken as example, it looks very similar - the procedure `DoSetMaxLength` - which will send the same message you are trying to send - will also be called in `TCustomEdit.CreateWnd`, at a time where there is a valid `Handle` created. A fix for your code would then look like this:

```
  TDUMMYEdit = class(TEdit)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FAllowValues : Boolean;
    FMaxLength: Integer;
    Procedure SetAllowValues(Value : Boolean);
    procedure SetMaxLength(Value: Integer);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure CreateWnd; override;    
  public
    { Public declarations }
  published
    { Published declarations }
    Property AllowValues : Boolean read FAllowValues write SetAllowValues;
    property MaxLength: Integer read FMaxLength write SetMaxLength default 0;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('DUMMY', [TDUMMYEdit]);
end;

{ TDUMMYEdit }

...
procedure TDUMMYEdit.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited CreateWnd;
  SendMessage(Handle, EM_LIMITTEXT, FMaxLength, 0);
end;
...
```

Comment: i am super new to component creation and i am playing around. i will check Createwnd.

Comment: Glad to hear. I added the solution with your original code and `CreateWnd`, too.

Comment: Another way: you could  just inherit the maxlength property and all problems will be gone. but I have learned something new today. thank you (the +1 was from me)

Comment: Thank you @NasreddineAbdelillahGalfout, I realized that MaxLength was already in one of the base classes when my answer was first formulated. I emphasized that this is a possible easy solution to remove the one in TDUMMYEdit.